# Android - timer working after app is background

Tags: android

Good morning,

I have a problem with android app. I want to write simple countdown timer working in background. The timer should count event if user use other app. I know that i should use foreground service to achieve this, but i use `Strava` app to track my running. And there aren't any notification (from foreground service) and even if i kill app, it will keep tracking.

Thank you in advance for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I use Strava.  There's a notification.  I just double checked because I'm sure I saw one.

Secondly, for something as simple as Strava you wouldn't really need one.  You could just write the time you start to disc, then when you come back to the foreground get the new time and subtract.  What Strava needs the foreground service for is to keep the GPS running for the mapping, and the pedometer for the step count.